# request.getParameter on <a>

Tags: java, html, parameters, request, submit

I current have some instances of input buttons and use request.getParameter to the request when the button is clicked. Like this:

```
<input type ="submit" name="test" value="test"/>

String t = request.getParameter("test");
    if (t != null) {
        System.out.print("k");
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a similar method for submitting data from a link , but I have not seen to come across any. In other words, I want to use a link  instead for  for the same result.

The application use servlets and the method="get" to handle the submit.

Comment: Could you give us please a bit more context on the app? Is it a Spring app? Or just some Servlets? Do you handle this request on POST or on GET?

Comment: The application only use servlets and handles the request with method="get". I'll edit the question to include these informations aswell.

Comment: Well, it should work if you have the anchor as `<a href="/your-path?test=valueOfTest">link</a>`

Comment: Thank you! This worked

Comment: I'll post an official answer for this :)

Comment: Would be great :) I'll accept it - again thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the parameters through GET, then you should send them as query parameters, like: `?key1=value1&key2=value2`.

For your use case, it should work if you replace the input type with the anchor element:

```
<a href="/your-path?test=value">link</a>
```

As a side note, just make sure that you understand the difference between GET and POST. Some notes [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/get-vs-post), or simply Google it. What you've tried, with the input submit element should be handled via POST, it's really strange that it even worked in the first place.